# MySQL Server is Restarting automatically after some minutes

Tags: mysql

I am getting an Issue after everey 2-3 minutes

```
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    57
```

I am really not able to find why it is happening. I saw to my error log it says

```
120419  0:36:03  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 93884, file name /EBSmnt/mysql/mysql-bin.000233
120419  0:36:04  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1692 2597076235
120419  0:36:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120419  0:36:04 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.43-enterprise-gpl-advanced-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (G
```

Can Anybody please tell How to handle the Scenario.It is on one of the Production Server.

**EDIT**

RAM is of 7GB.

And InnoDB Configuration in my.cnf are

```
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_data_home_dir = /lvm/mysql
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:80G:autoextend
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 1300M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
```

Comment: Please show your my.cnf and how much RAM you have

Comment: Did your production machine have a MySQL crash or server crash recently ???

Comment: Please run this query and tell me the result : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA : I have updated the things in question.Actually we are starting the work on it from today so i don't know what happens to it in previous days.Our Client Reported that we are facing such issue.When i saw i was not also able to understand what is going on there.

Comment: mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
Result is  16777216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) and the presence of a large TEXT/BLOB field.

I answered two questions in the past that involved mysql crashing because of the max_allowed_packet being too small.

- [MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323)
- [InnoDB table SELECT returns ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away (after power outage)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/innodb-table-select-returns-error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away-after/14283#14283)

I recommend raising your max_allowed_packet to the max value, which is 1GB

If you have TEXT/BLOB fields, you may have entered a TEXT/BLOB field that is too big to pass through a [**MySQL Packet**](https://superuser.com/a/273833/76764) or through the InnoDB Log Files. You may need to resize your innodb log files to the max value, which is 2047M. Here is what to do:

STEP 01) Add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=1G
innodb_log_file_size=2047M
```

NOTE: In Google Cloud, you can't enter 1G, you must use the value 1073741824

STEP 02) `service mysql stop`

STEP 03) `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01]`

STEP 04) `service mysql start`

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL error log shown in the question you don't have any issues with the MySQL server.

Error message on MySQL client prompt:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

...is because of two connection timeout variables namely `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout`.

If your connection is idle for more than `interactive_timeout` seconds your connection will get disconnected automatically.

Comment: An incorrect setting is an issue with the server, I think :)