# Error when dropping InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to drop a database in mysql, but every time I get this error

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

even logged in as root.

Originally, I had a corrupted table that I could not recreate, hence I decided to recreate the db. I have innodb file per table, not sure if that matters.

How can I drop this database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot drop the database.

The problem comes the table that is corrupt. It's not necessarily the `.ibd` file. It is, more than likely, the data dictionary entry within ibdata1 ([**See pictorial representation of ibdata1**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)).

I wrote about this back on `Mar 02, 2012` : [InnoDB table SELECT returns ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away (after power outage)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/innodb-table-select-returns-error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away-after/14283#14283)

Although tedious, here is what you can do to save the other tables in that corrupt database `bad_db`:

STEP 01) `USE bad_db`

STEP 02) Run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tablename;` for every table in `bad_db`. Collect all table names that do not crash mysqld when you attempt to run the count.

STEP 03) Run `mysqldump -u... -p... bad_db table1 table2 ... tableN > bad_db_goodtables.sql` 
for all the tables that did not crash mysqld.

If you are going to use a different database name, then reload `bad_db_goodtables.sql` into that new database.

If you need the database to be the same name, BAD NEWS !!! You will have overhaul ibdata1. There are more steps:

STEP 04) mysqldump all the other databases into separate dump files

STEP 05) Perform InnoDB Infrastructure Cleanup ([**See my `Oct 29, 2010` StackOverflow Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/491757))

STEP 06) Reload all the other mysqldumps good databases.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Much appreciated Rolando! Fantastic reply. Wish there was a way to repair that db. Would have liked it to be the same name :)

Comment: I ran MySQL for a while now, had this happen the first time the other day, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How can you perform InnoDB infrastructure cleanup if you cannot drop the database and the step #2 of the cleanup is to drop all databases?

Comment: Probably a rare situation, but I had this happen while restoring a dump as a background job.  The parent terminal died, and the db couldn't be dropped until the restore connection was killed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check MySQL (MariaDB) log. The problem may be about InnoDB. If it is the case, you can disable InnoDB and then drop the database. Then you can enable it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772611/how-to-disable-innodb-in-mysql) is how you can disable InnoDB.

In my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine = myisam
```