# Probably missing something simple, source of ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-8.0

Looking to import a mysqldump .sql file into a new db.

Have tried both via command line and directly within a mysql session.

The following call gives the assocaited error:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/media/chris/T7$ sudo mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u admin -p -D op < op_prices.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 25: Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine
```

Getting the following after trying to do the import within a MySQL session:

```
mysql> use op; 
Database changed 
mysql> source /media/chris/T7/op_prices.sql 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 168 - 'Unknown (generic) error from engine' from storage engine Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'op.prices' doesn't exist
```

`op.prices` is the table present in the .sql dump.  Not sure what would be giving this/these errors though.

The dump finished successfully and is close to half a TB in size, so don't think it's likely to have been corrupted.  Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Best regards, Chris

Comment: Do you have enough space in your disk? Also, could be any limitation in your configuration. Check out this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138505/receiving-general-error-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine)

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães Yeah, close to 5T

Comment: Then have you taken a look in the link I sent? It might help, one of the answers say this: 

`Check your OS open file limit (for the mysql user) - ulimit -a and open files or maybe file locks for values between 256-512 (160 tables created, each having ibd/frm or frm/myi/myd for possible myisam table means a bit over 300 files) and try to make it higher.`

I