# Aruba-MySQL: can't create/change table to engine=INNODB

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

We have our database stored in aruba (mysql.aruba.it) where there is a table called "task". Because of many changes in the requirements we decided to drop the table and create it again from 0 with different fields and constraints. The problem is that MySQL/Aruba won't let us create a called "task" table anymore. Or better, we can create another task table only with engine MyISAM but we need INNODB because we will use contraints and foreign keys in the table. So I have tried to create a MyISAM table and then convert it into INNODB but I get an error like this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `task` ENGINE = INNODB
#1025 - Error on rename of './Sql689345_4/#sql-6962_1891f' to './Sql689345_4/task' (errno: -1)
```

I don't know why there is this problem with this table: for other tables we have we can drop them and re-create them as many times as we want. 
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please run `SHOW ENGINES;` Does InnoDB appear in the list ? Does the `Support` columns say `YES` or `DEFAULT` ?

Comment: Yes InnoDB is supported because up to now I've always used it and all the othee tables are InnoDB... "Task" tables has references to other two tables: clients and projestcs. Should I drop them too to reset everything and make task tables be InnoDB again?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the InnoDB Internals (Picture from Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB]

Please note the data dictionary inside ibdata1 (the system tablespace)

It sounds like you have a broken data dictionary entry on the `task` table when it existed

The only way around would be move all the tables into another database.

For starters, suppose you have database `mydb1`. Create another database `mydb2`

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb2;
```

For example, to move `mydb1.mytable` into `mydb2`, do this

```
ALTER TABLE mydb1.mytable RENAME mydb2.mytable;
```

Move all your tables sideways into `mydb2`.

You would then have to drop your old database

```
DROP DATABASE mydb1;
```

You should be able to convert the `task` table in `mydb2` into InnoDB.

```
USE mydb2
ALTER TABLE `task` ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I've understood the problem. Anyway I'm afraid I'm not allowed to create another DB where to move/copy the tables because that aruba account and the DB aren't mine but of my boss. Are you sure that also after dropping the tables that were referenced in the task table, the dictionary won't clean anyway?

Comment: You are not dropping the tables, you are renaming them so they land in another database. You may have to talk to the sysadmin for Aruba for assistance in this. Of course, make sure the sysadmin does a back of MySQL beforehand. You may also have to talk to the Dev Team to explain the situation

Comment: As for the data dictionary, that "pidgeon hole" will still remain, pointing to the old database. The only way to make ibdata1 clean would be to dump all the data, stop mysql, delete ibdata1, start mysql, and reload the data. (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/innodb-table-select-returns-error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away-afte/14283#14283)

Comment: I understand, ok...I will ask my boss if he can drop the DB and create another one...thank you